# Is their a way to store strings in a function so that when you return it is there to view? This is in python

Tags: python, list

I want to store strings in a function so I can keep track of it. Every time I visit the function I want to add to that list, so that when I return to that function I can view the inventory. Whenever I leave the function the list is gone, so how can I keep an inventory of the strings in that function, so that when I return to that function I can view the present added strings. Below is a sample functions, which I use the append function to add the strings. This is in python.

```py
def prize_inventory(p):

    name = ['Here is your inventory: ']

    a = 'Pandora\'s Box'
    b = 'Armor'
    c = 'Mystical Book'
    d = 'Helmet'
    e = 'Sword'
    f = 'Magical Pen'

    if p == 'Pandora\'s Box':
        print("\nYou have grabbed the", p)
        name.append(a)

    if p == 'Armor':
        print("\nYou have grabbed the", p)
        name.append(b)

    if p == 'Mystical Book':
        print("\nYou have grabbed the", p)
        name.append(c)

    if p == 'Helmet':
        print("\nYou have grabbed the", p)
        name.append(d)

    if p == 'Sword':
        print("\nYou have grabbed the", p)
        name.append(e)

    if p == 'Magical Pen':
        print("\nYou have grabbed the", p)
        name.append(f)
        
    print("\nYou so far have the following items", name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you store the inventory in a list or dict.  You pass that structure into the function and change it within the function.  For instance:

```
def prize_inventory(p, invent):
    
    print("\nYou have grabbed the", p)
    invent.append(p)

inventory = []
prize_inventory("Sword", inventory)
prize_inventory("Helmet", inventory)
print(inventory)
```

Output:

```
You have grabbed the Sword

You have grabbed the Helmet
['Sword', 'Helmet']
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define your list globally(outside of your function).
For example:

```python
def prize_inventory(p, inventory):
  items = ['Pandora\'s Box', 'Armor', 'Mystical Book', 'Helmet', 'Sword', 'Magical Pen']
  if p in items:
    inventory.append(p)
  print("\nYou so far have the following items", inventory)


my_inventory = list()
prize_inventory('Armor', my_inventory)
```

Comment: Thank You very much! This is what I was looking for. I appreciate all your help.